# Rayleigh Distribution: $P[X > 2] =1 - P[X \le 2] = 1 - F[2]$

Tags: probability-distributions

My notes give the following explanation of the Rayleigh distribution:

> The Rayleigh distribution has CDF $F(x) = 1 - e^{-x^2/2}, x > 0$. To get the PDF, we differentiate the CDF, which gives
>
> $f(x) = xe^{-x^2 / 2}, \ x > 0.$
>
> For $x \le 0$ both the CDF and PDF are equal to $0$.
>
> Let $X \sim$ Rayleigh. To find $P(X > 2)$:
>
> $$P[X > 2] = \int_2^\infty x e ^{-x^2/2} \ dx = 1 - F(2) \approx 0.14$$

For the last part, my understanding is that the author used symmetry to show that $P[X > 2] =1 - P[X \le 2] = 1 - F[2]$, right?

Comment: It is direct that $P(X>2)=1-F(2)$. No symmetry involved but just $$1=P(X>2)+P(X\leq2)$$

Comment: @drhab What do you mean that it is "direct" and that no symmetry is involved? Isn't this an implication of the symmetry of the distribution curve?

Comment: I mean direct in the sense that $$1=P(\Omega)=P(A\cup A^{\complement})=P(A)+P(A^{\complement})$$ is a property of probability measures. I do not recognize any symmetry in this.

Comment: @drhab Ohh, sorry, I was thinking of the symmetry of the normal distribution; my mistake. And I see what you mean now. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @ThePointer Note that $1-F(2)=1-\frac1{e^2}$

Comment: @callculus I understand now. Thanks.

Comment: @ThePointer Nice. I wasn't sure if you knew how to calculate the integral.